# CI/CD: "ResourceDeploymentFailure" when deploying an Azure Data Factory with Managed private endpoint

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-data-factory

I'm facing a problem while deploying an ADF project in the prod stage off my CI/CD pipeline.

- I'm using Azure DevOps.
- I'm using a release pipeline, triggered when a new build is available (each validated PR on the main branch triggers a new build).
- Each release pipeline has two stages : staging and prod.

I am using a *managed private endpoint* connecting an ADLS account. This was causing me some problems ([example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/386892/unable-to-override-the-managedendpoint-resource-id.html)), but I got it to work in the staging phase. I can now successfully deploy in staging.

I then cloned the staging stage in the release pipeline, and changed the ARM parameters in the *ARM Template deployment* activity. However, that activity fail in the prod stage and gives me a generic error message :

```json
##[error]Conflict: {
  "status": "Failed",
  "error": {
    "code": "ResourceDeploymentFailure",
    "message": "The resource operation completed with terminal provisioning state 'Failed'."
  }
}
```

I use others activities (PowerShell scripts to stop the trigger etc.) that work correctly.

When I go to my prod ADF, I can see that the pipelines, datasets and linked services are successfully deployed, but the managed private endpoint provisioning status appear as *failed*. I tried different things with no success, the relevant facts are:

- I use an Azure DevOps service connection (ARM) with Contributor role at the prod subscription level.
- My ADF is in the rg-adf-prod ressource prod, while ADLS is in the rg-dw-prod ressource group (both rg are in the prod subscription).

I know that the problem has to do with that managed private endpoint but I cannot figure what. I deleted it several times, even tried to use a subscription deployment scope in the ARM Template deployment activity, with no luck. Also, I tried to create a new storage account and put it in the same ressource group as the ADF (as I do in staging), still not luck.

Below are the YAML definition of the *ARM Template deployment* activity in the staging stage (successful) and prod stage (error).

Staging:

```yaml
steps:
- task: AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3
  displayName: 'ARM Template deployment: Resource Group scope'
  inputs:
    azureResourceManagerConnection: ADevopsAdfStg
    subscriptionId: '<dev test sub id>'
    resourceGroupName: 'rg-adf-stg'
    location: 'France Central'
    csmFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/ADF_ARN_BUILD/AdfArmTemplates/ARMTemplateForFactory.json'
    csmParametersFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/ADF_ARN_BUILD/AdfArmTemplates/ARMTemplateParametersForFactory.json'
    overrideParameters: '-factoryName "adfalexpocstg" -DATALAKE_properties_typeProperties_url "https://<stg adls>.dfs.core.windows.net/" -AzureDataLakeStorage1_properties_privateLinkResourceId "/subscriptions/<dev test sub id>/resourceGroups/rg-adf-stg/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/<stg adls>"'
  timeoutInMinutes: 20
```

Prod:

```yaml
steps:
- task: AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3
  displayName: 'ARM Template deployment: Resource Group scope'
  inputs:
    azureResourceManagerConnection: ADevopsProd
    subscriptionId: '<prod sub id>'
    resourceGroupName: 'rg-adf-prod'
    location: 'France Central'
    csmFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/ADF_ARN_BUILD/AdfArmTemplates/ARMTemplateForFactory.json'
    csmParametersFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/ADF_ARN_BUILD/AdfArmTemplates/ARMTemplateParametersForFactory.json'
    overrideParameters: '-factoryName "adfalexpocprod" -DATALAKE_properties_typeProperties_url "https://<prod adls>.dfs.core.windows.net/" -AzureDataLakeStorage1_properties_privateLinkResourceId "/subscriptions/<prod sub id>/resourceGroups/rg-dw-prod/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/<prod adls>"'
  timeoutInMinutes: 20
```

Thank you

Comment: Please share your ARM template for your managed private endpoints. Where do you see the error? In the Azure DevOps release pipeline runs or in the Azure portal deployments?

Comment: Hi, I see the error in the DevOps release Pipeline.

Comment: Can you check the deployments in the Azure portal?

Comment: The deployment for the managed private endpoin in ADF is "failed".